# Calculation of singular support

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, microlocal-analysis

I know that the singular support of $\delta(x)$ is $\{0\}$. Now, I want to calculate the singular support of $\delta(x-y)$, where this is a distribution acting on $\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n) \otimes \mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$? I am assuming there is no smooth function locally representing this distribution, but I have no idea how to start.

Comment: No, both the *support* and the *singular support* of $\delta$ is $\{0\}$.

Comment: What’s the definition of singular support you’re using?

Comment: The usual one. It was my mistake. What is confusing for me is that delta distribution acts this time on the tensor product and not just in the Schwartz space. So since we have to consider every $x$ and $y$ I thought the singular support would be the union of all $\{a\}$ resulting in $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Comment: The singular support of $\delta(t)$ is the set $\{0\}$ so we can expect the singular support of $\delta(x-y)$ to be the set $\{ (x,y) \mid x-y=0\}$.